# Parsing error while installing an application in android?

Tags: android, installation, apk

While i'm installing an APK file from SD card, I got a Parse error inside the Package Installer..
The error is:
       "There is a problem parsing the package"

Can anyone help me??

Thanks!!

Comment: No i never renamed the APK file.

Comment: Have you ever installed the application and then uninstall ed it,then again installing..Seems like signature mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this error too.  I installed my app, removed it, updated with some new code, and attempted to install again.  To resolve, I bumped up the android:versionCode in the manifest.